# Porque o servidor jboss trava e não executa com o comando standalone.bat?

Tags: java, jboss

Estou tentando configurar o JBoss e já pesquisei em diversos lugares meu problema. Mas ainda não consegui resolver. Mudei a porta http padrão do no arquivo `jboss\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` da seguinte maneira `<socket-binding name="http" port="8089"/>`. Isso porque meu Oracle developer roda na porta 8080. configurei a variável de ambiente `JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121` e estou utilizando windows 7 32 bits. Quando executo o comando standalone.bat a execução fica da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
e não continua execução
então não consigo rodar o servidor no navegador com http://localhos:8089. Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Aparentemente versões mais antigas do JBoss não se dão muito bem com Java 8. Podes neste caso tentar utilizar um Java JDK 1.7 ou então dar um upgrade e utilizar uma versão do WildFly. Para mais informações, podes checar este [link](https://developer.jboss.org/message/808212)